# Ctrl-C Not working in zsh

Tags: zsh

In zsh when I try and press `CTRL-C` nothing happens (it works fine in bash) when I run `bindkey | grep \\^C` I get `"^C" Applications` so something must've happened... how do I bind `^-C` to the default?

Comment: What are you trying to do with Ctrl-c? What does `stty -a` show (with respect to `intr` and `^C` (in a freshly started zsh session)?

Comment: go to a new line in the shell, and `intr = ^C;`

Answer (score 11):

`stty sane` is usually a good starting place; outside of the `zsh` command line editor, it's a function of the terminal driver.

Comment: now `bindkey | grep \\^C` returns nothing...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe another issue is the shell trap is set to something else.
( see [Ctrl-C not working on MacOS/Zsh](https://superuser.com/questions/1783488/ctrl-c-not-working-on-macos-zsh/1789099#1789099) )

`trap INT`

resets this and fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, something had changed the zsh interrupt key (*intr*) to Control-G.  To fix it:

```
stty intr ^C
```

(`stty sane` did not work.)

More detail:

```
% stty -a | grep intr
    eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^G; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
% # Control-C did not work. So I used Control-Z to stop the ping:
% ping 1.2.3.4
PING 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
^CRequest timeout for icmp_seq 1
^CRequest timeout for icmp_seq 2
^Z
zsh: suspended  ping 1.2.3.4
% stty intr ^C
% stty -a | grep intr
    eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
# Control-C is working again.  Yes!
% ping 1.2.3.4
PING 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
^C
--- 1.2.3.4 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this situation by typing in the simple command `ls` after pressing ctrl-c, ctrl-c.

I think I was in some kind of multi-line input mode.