# Ctrl-C not working on MacOS/Zsh

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I have a similar problem to [Ctrl-C Not working in zsh](https://superuser.com/questions/253402/ctrl-c-not-working-in-zsh)

But it is not the `stty` setting or the key-bindings.
It definitely happened in one terminal, while on others it works.

I get: from stty:
`eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;`

Changing the intr to some other key, makes the Ctrl-C ring-the-bell but the other key does nothing.

Ctrl-Z works, Ctrl-C does not.

I checked the ZSH settings/environment and compared to a good terminal - but I didn't see anything suspicious/obvious.

When I use ssh to connect somewhere else, Ctrl-C works.

running `stty raw; xxd`  nicely prints "03" for Ctrl-C..
Without the `stay raw` xxd does get no "03" key at all.

Reset & Hard-Reset the terminal makes no difference.

Even sending `kill -INT` to any process running in the bad terminal is ignored.

As if the signal mask is disabled.

Any ideas how to get the zsh back the interrupt signal? (aside from killing the window, that is...)

Answer (score 4):

It seems doing
`trap "echo hello" INT`
and then remove the trap handler using `trap INT` put the signal mask back into the correct form.

Ctrl-C now works again.... (weird how that happed I am still wondering..)